# JavaScript String Replace and post back to RadTextBox on Paste

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex

I have a RadTextBox:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="txtBox" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="635px" TabIndex="2" Rows="6" runat="server" onpaste="JavaScript:return RestrictCopyPaste();"></telerik:RadTextBox>
```

Calling the following JavaScript function when it's pasted to the textbox:

```
    function RestrictCopyPaste() {
        var txt = clipboardData.getData('Text')
        txt = txt.replace("[^\u0000-\u007F]", "");
        document.getElementById("<%= txtBox.ClientID%>").value = txt
    }
```

I want to replace every character in that regular expression code with a blank string. The purpose of this is to remove all non ASCII chars on paste. Currently when I copy and paste into the text box it is just duplicating what I'm pasting.

Any idea on how to get this to work?

Comment: Use double backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What is the purpose of adding double backslashes? Do you mean this? [^\\u0000-\\u007F] . I'm getting the same result.

Comment: Well, "[^\u0000-\u007F]" is passed to the RegExp constructor and thus, the backslashes muts be doubled . Or use a regex literal: `txt = txt.replace(/[^\x00-\x7F]/, "");` If it does not work, check the `clipboard.getData` piece of code. I see it does not work in Chrome, and works in IE.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help I was able to get it working for IE, now I just need to fix the replace so it replaces all occurences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a regex literal with a `/g` modifier:

```
txt = txt.replace(/[^\u0000-\u007F]/g, "");
```

Else, you need to use a RegExp constructor notation like this:

```
txt = txt.replace(RegExp("[^\\u0000-\\u007F]", "g"), "");
```

Comment: I used the second option.  I also had to add code in order to get the code from actually completing the paste, which is why it was appearing twice. So now it just uses the text I'm setting after the replace.